# How do I parse XML data returned by a "GET" request in JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, get, xml-parsing

So i'm making a "Follower Counter" for a small media company. I've set up a get request to return the Twitter API XML file that contains the number of followers. I know that the get request is set up correctly because it works when I hard code the success function. The issue that I'm having is an inability to use the xml data that is being returned. I need to parse the xml to get the required tag, and then update my $('#followCounter').html. So how can I do this.

Here is my current jQuery:

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=nightoutinc';    
$.get(url, {
dataType: 'xml',
success: function (twitterAPI){ 

var twitter = $(twitterAPI 'follower_count').html();
$('#followCounter').html(twitter);

alert('success');


}
```

I'm not getting any console errors. The XML can be found here: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=nightoutinc

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the JSONP datatype to make cross-domain requests.

`http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=nightoutinc&callback=??`

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=nightoutinc&callback=??';
$.getJSON(url,  function(twitterAPI) {
        console.log(twitterAPI)
        var twitter = twitterAPI.followers_count;
        $('#followCounter').html(twitter);

        alert(twitter);


});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JsyFV/)**